# Select range ID with the highest score using foverlaps in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I would like to select the range ID with the greatest quantity taken from a separate column using `foverlaps`, in a setting where a value falls between overlapping ranges. Although I'm quite familiar with the basic settings of the package I couldn't find a methodology to perform the above function.

Here is a small example

```
>df1
AthleteID  Distance
Athlete1   5
Athlete2   10
Athlete3   25

>df2
CheckpointID   Start   End Score
Checkpoint1    1       8   2
Checkpoint2    7       12  4
Checkpoint3    9       15  6
Checkpoint4    16      26  8
Checkpoint5    20      30  10
```

According to the above the final data.frame should look like this

```
>df1
AthleteID  Distance   Score  CheckpointID
Athlete1   5          2      Checkpoint1
Athlete2   10         6      Checkpoint3
Athlete3   25         10     Checkpoint5
```

=========================

**edit**

One final question; I am also interested in knowing how to use different checkpoint scores (same intervals) according to the athlete ID. Here's a modified score table

```
>df2
CheckpointID   AthleteID   Start   End Score
Checkpoint1    Athlete1    1       8   2
Checkpoint2    Athlete1    7       12  4
Checkpoint3    Athlete1    9       15  6
Checkpoint4    Athlete1    16      26  8
Checkpoint5    Athlete1    20      30  10
Checkpoint1    Athlete2    1       8   3
Checkpoint2    Athlete2    7       12  5
Checkpoint3    Athlete2    9       15  7
Checkpoint4    Athlete2    16      26  9
Checkpoint5    Athlete2    20      30  11
Checkpoint1    Athlete3    1       8   1
Checkpoint2    Athlete3    7       12  3
Checkpoint3    Athlete3    9       15  5
Checkpoint4    Athlete3    16      26  7
Checkpoint5    Athlete3    20      30  11
```

So the final outcome looks like this

```
>df1
AthleteID  Distance   Score  CheckpointID
Athlete1   5          2      Checkpoint1
Athlete2   10         7      Checkpoint3
Athlete3   25         11     Checkpoint5
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it using the newly implemented `non-equi` joins which should be more straightforward...

```
y[x, on = .(Start <= Distance, End >= Distance), mult = "last", 
    .(AthleteID, Distance, Score, CheckpointID)]
```

---

where,

```
x=fread("AthleteID  Distance
        Athlete1   5
        Athlete2   10
        Athlete3   25
        ")
y=fread("CheckpointID   Start   End Score
    Checkpoint1    1       8   2
    Checkpoint2    7       12  4
    Checkpoint3    9       15  6
    Checkpoint4    16      26  8
    Checkpoint5    20      30  10
    ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've made a small edit before picking the best answer and closing this question, so please check it out!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `foverlaps` that way. The key is to duplicate `Distance` column in `df1` to create an artifical interval with start equals to end. Then, use `foverlaps` to join `df1` and `df2` for rows where `[Distance, Distance2 (=Distance)]` falls within `[Start, End]` of `df2`, and keep only last match.

```r
library(data.table)

df1 <- fread("
AthleteID  Distance
Athlete1   5
Athlete2   10
Athlete3   25
")

df2 <- fread("
CheckpointID   Start   End Score
Checkpoint1    1       8   2
Checkpoint2    7       12  4
Checkpoint3    9       15  6
Checkpoint4    16      26  8
Checkpoint5    20      30  10
")

# Need a duplicated temp column as end of interval
df1[, Distance2 := Distance]
#>    AthleteID Distance Distance2
#> 1:  Athlete1        5         5
#> 2:  Athlete2       10        10
#> 3:  Athlete3       25        25

# y must be keyed in foverlaps
setkey(df2, Start, End)

# use type within and mult last, then select column
foverlaps(df1, df2, by.x = c("Distance", "Distance2"), mult = "last", type = "within")[, .(AthleteID, Distance, Score, CheckpointID)]
#>    AthleteID Distance Score CheckpointID
#> 1:  Athlete1        5     2  Checkpoint1
#> 2:  Athlete2       10     6  Checkpoint3
#> 3:  Athlete3       25    10  Checkpoint5

# Delete temp column in df1
df1[, Distance2 := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've made a small edit before picking the best answer and closing this question, so please check it out!